# AsyncTask, network operations and timeouts

Tags: android, networking

I am performing a network operation, on an AsyncTask;

```
try {               
    int timeOut = 5000;             
    httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeOut);

    client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    request = new HttpGet(URL);

    response = client.execute(request);
    in = null;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    line = in.readLine();
} catch (Exception e) {     
    return "ERROR CONNECTING TO SERVER";
}
```

I am struggling with timeouts, and slow connections.

If is taking more than 5 seconds to retrieve the data, then I am getting a timeout exception.
I understand that if the task is not completed in 5 seconds then it will timeout, but what if it has contacted the server, and is currently downloading data that takes more than 5 seconds to download.

I do not wish to set the timeout to 20 seconds as it is too long to wait if there is a problem contacting the server.

Is there another way I should be doing this, instead of using the timeout?

It may be that my understanding is floored, and that timeout is ignored once the server has been reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the server is contacted, you will be able to read the first portion of data almost immediately. A line taking more than 1 second to transfer is likely a glitch. Anyway, the timeout will not fire on a connection with activity, it is meant to start ticking on stalled connections.

Note that a 5-second timeout is something that your users will experience relatively often, so you have to handle the condition correctly. To debug the branch that executes on timeout, I'd suggest to temporarily choose a very small timeout value so that you could easily reproduce the exception.

Comment: Thank you for the info.
So am I correct that when the server has been reached, the timeout is ignored, even if the server takes a long time to respond? 
This is because I sometimes have a large amount of data that can take up to 10 seconds to download.